# Hollow Square Number Pattern

Tags: java

I am trying to create something like an asterisk rectangle shape.

Hereby is my code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Exercise2 {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        boolean check = false;
        
        while (check != true){
            System.out.println("Enter an integer between 1 and 20: ");
            int num = scanner.nextInt();
            if (num > 0 && num <= 20){
                for (int i=1; i<=num; i++){
                    for (int j=1; j<=num; j++){
                        if (i == 1 || i == num || j == 1 || j == num) { 
                              System.out.print(j + " ");
                        } else {
                            System.out.print("  "); // Two spaces for inner area
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
                check = false;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Number not between 1 and 20. Exiting.");
                check = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting to get this.

`Enter an integer between 1 and 20: 5`

`output:`

```
1 2 3 4 5
2       4
3       3
4       2
5 4 3 2 1
```

But I don't know where I should amend to get to this. Please help. Thank you

this is what my code displays.

```
1 2 3 4 5
1       5
1       5
1       5
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: @ValerijDobler the current output is

1 2 3 4 5
1          5
1         5
1 2 3 4 5

Comment: i added in my question.

Comment: noted. sorry for that @ValerijDobler

Comment: What is the expected format for double digit?

Answer (score 0):

I would build an algorithm to do three things:

1. Iterate the numbers 1..n
2. The gab is always floor(n-2) numbers, so you can pad this in this step. And add k = 2..n-1 and t = n-1..2 at the ends.
3. Iterate the numbers n..1

I'd recommend you tackle this problem for yourself with the aforementioned outline. Here is a solution to check against:

This code works for single digit numbers:

```java
public static String print(int n) {
    final var sb = new StringBuilder();
    // Step 1
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        sb.append(i);
        if (i != n) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
    }
    if (n > 1) {
        sb.append("\n");
        // Step 2
        if (n > 2) {
            final var gap = " ".repeat((n - 1) * 2 - 1);
            for (int k = 2; k < n; ++k) {
                final var t = n - k + 1;
                sb.append(k).append(gap).append(t).append("\n");
            }
        }
        // Step 3
        for (int i = n; i >= 1; --i) {
            sb.append(i);
            if (i != 1) {
                sb.append(" ");
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Note: `String.repeat(n)` was added in Java 11.

Answer (score 0):

I would split this pattern into 3 parts. The first row, the middle rows, and the bottom row.

The first row is relatively easy. Just print the numbers from 1 to `num` inclusive.

```
for (int i=1; i<=num; i++){
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

The middle rows follow a pattern like this:

```
2        num - 1
3        num - 2
4        num - 3
...
num - 3        4
num - 2        3
num - 1        2
```

It goes from `2` to `num - 1`, and the numbers on the side always add up to `num + 1`.

As for how many spaces you should print in between, you can first calculate the width of the entire rectangle. First count how many numbers there needs to be, add one for each space that follows each number (there are `num - 1` spaces in total). Finally, add one for each two digit number, because they need an extra space.

```
int rectangleWidth;
rectangleWidth = num * 2 - 1;
if (num >= 10) {
    rectangleWidth += num - 9; // num - 9 is how many two digit numbers there are
}
```

The number of empty spaces to print is the rectangle's width minus the number of digits of the number on the left. You can further subtract the number of digits of the number on the right from this, so that the number on the right aligns.

```
for (int i = 2 ; i <= num - 1 ; i++) {
    int left = i;
    int right = num + 1 - i;
    int emptyCount = rectangleWidth - (left > 9 ? 2 : 1) - (right > 9 ? 2 : 1);
    System.out.print(left);
    System.out.print(" ".repeat(emptyCount));
    System.out.println(right);
}
```

Finally, the last row is the numbers going in decreasing order. Note that the last row should only exist if `num > 1`. The middle rows should only exist if `num > 2`, but we already encoded that in the stopping condition of the loop `i <= num - 1`.

```
if (num > 1) {
    for (int i = num; i >= 1; i--) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```java
String draw(int v) {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= v; i++) {
        if (i != 1) s.append(' ');
        s.append(i);
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <= v - 1; i++) {
        s.append('\n');
        s.append(i);
        s.append(" ".repeat((v * 2) - 3));
        s.append(v - i + 1);
    }
    s.append('\n');
    for (int i = v; i >= 1; i--) {
        if (i != v) s.append(' ');
        s.append(i);
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

Output

```
1 2 3 4 5
2       4
3       3
4       2
5 4 3 2 1
```

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2               8
3               7
4               6
5               5
6               4
7               3
8               2
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```